# Virtualbox with Android on MacOS

Tags: macos, virtualbox, macos-catalina, android-x86

Same virtualbox version with same Android version works fine on Windows 7, but doesn't work on MacOS 10.15

And the computer running windows has lower specs than the Macbook running Macos.

On Macos it boots, but it stops at the console. Basically it doesn't enter the graphical user interface

Comment: Are you using the same settings? Have you copied the machine or created it from scratch?

Comment: Same settings. I created new machine using the x86 official Android image

Comment: It is not difficult to copy a VBox VM between two computers, the benefit being it is already configured and working. Is there some reason you have not tried that?

Comment: but it's the same image I downloaded, and I configured it the same way.